# Android NotificationListenerService get EXTRA_SMALL_ICON always returns null

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-drawable, android-bitmap

I'm developing an app to read active notifications of Android. So far I have being successful until I got stucked with getting EXTRA_SMALL_ICON. I use following piece of code to retrive app icon and large icon and they both work just fine.

//Works fine

```
Drawable appIcon = null;
try {
     appIcon = getPackageManager().getApplicationIcon(packageName);
} catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

//Works fine

```
Bitmap largeIcon = null;
try {
    largeIcon = (Bitmap) notification.extras.getParcelable(Notification.EXTRA_LARGE_ICON);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

//NOT WORKING

```
Bitmap smallIcon = null;
   try {
        smallIcon = (Bitmap) notification.extras.getParcelable(Notification.EXTRA_SMALL_ICON);
   } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
   }
```

Getting SMALL_ICON throws following exception.

```
Key android.icon expected Parcelable but value was a java.lang.Integer.  The default value <null> was returned.
W/Bundle: Attempt to cast generated internal exception:
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to android.os.Parcelable
```

And yes, the notification I'm trying to get has a small icon set. Am I doing anything wrong or is there any other way to gt SMALL_ICON? I can not figure out why.

Thanks!

Comment: Small icon is passed as a drawable resource ID not a bitmap. The same way a notification is built.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try changing it to this

```
Bitmap smallIcon = null;
try {
    int id = notification.extras.getInt(Notification.EXTRA_SMALL_ICON);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

after that use this

```
    String pack = sbn.getPackageName(); 
    Context remotePackageContext = null; 
    Bitmap bmp = null;
    try {  
        remotePackageContext = getApplicationContext().createPackageContext(pack, 0);  
        Drawable icon = remotePackageContext.getResources().getDrawable(id);  
        if(icon !=null) {  
            bmp = ((BitmapDrawable) icon).getBitmap();
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {  
        e.printStackTrace();  
    }
```

Comment: It says can not cast int to Bitmap.

Comment: i updated my answer, i think in this way you can get the bitmap from the int you've got from extra